# Create mouseover /tooltip text in matlab plot (treeplot)

Tags: matlab, plot, label, tooltip, mouseover

I created a treeplot to represent metabolic network reactions. The Endresult shall be a Hasse diagram.
Now I allready got the plot working and the nodes are also labeled with text. This text is the index of the reaction behind it.
These reactions have longer names and I need them to be shown, when you hover the mouse over it. Like a tooltip.
I tried uicontrols, get() and so on.

Problem ist, that treelayout only returns axis coordinates (map coords?) but for uicontrol I need the 4 distances in pixels. I tried map2pix, axes2pix and CData but couldn't figuere it out.

Maybe some of you guys has an idea how to create textboxes with tooltips in a plot?

Here some code that works out:

```
treeplot(nodes);
[x,y] = treelayout(nodes);
x = x'
y = y'
text(x(:,1), y(:,1), lables,     'VerticalAlignment','bottom','HorizontalAlignment','right') %lables is a cell array with strings
title({'Level Lines'},'FontSize',12,'FontName','Times New Roman');
camroll(180);
```

What I tried:

```
c = get(gca, 'CurrentPoint'); % get handles to children
xLimits = get(gca,'XLim');  %# Get the range of the x axis
yLimits = get(gca,'YLim');  %# Get the range of the y axis
xdata = get(gca,'XData')
map2pix(x(3,1),y(3,1))
test=['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'];
uicontrol('Units','points','Style','text','Position',[x(3,1),   y(3,1),20,20], 'String',lables(3), 'TooltipString','dings');
```

Output is something like:

```
x =

0.4167
0.1667
0.5000
0.8333
0.5000
0.3333
0.5833
0.5000
0.6667


y =

0.6667
0.1667
0.8333
0.1667
0.5000
0.1667
0.3333
0.1667
0.1667
```

I am happy and thankfull for every answer! 
Greetings from Berlin,
Mathias